# Android studio throws "Too much output to process error" on debug

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio throws "Too much output to process error" on debug.

I just started working on android development and trying to debug using my nexus 5 as a connected device.

Being a novice, I thought it was a memory issue and even closed all the background applications. In my single activity I am just displaying a background image and a button.

Please have a look at the layout xml...

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundimage"
android:weightSum="5"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#C9BDBD"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="#6C7B8B"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Become An Android Developer"
        android:onClick="Congratulations!!! You are now initiated.."/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Also its not showing my background image as well..just white background

Comment: please post a stack trace or an error log

Comment: What is the resolution of the image? It might be too high and that's why it won't render.

Comment: Hey Vucko..you were right.It was the resolution issue..Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Button's android:onClick should be a method in the Java code.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:background="#6C7B8B"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="Become An Android Developer"
    android:onClick="Congratulations!!! You are now initiated.."/>
```

something like

```
android:onClick="doSomthing"/>
```

and in the Java code:

```
public void doSomthing(View v){
...
...
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shahar..the method worked..I must have interpreted the syntax wrongly from the tutorial.. Although the background is still not showing on the device while its still there on layout preview

Answer (score 1):

As far as "too much output..." issue is concerned, you can mostly ignore it.  Still it would make sense if you remove some of the really unnecessary Log lines from your code, especially from methods that are called repeatedly and frequently.

Another thing, i believe you want to show a text "Congratulations!!! You are now initiated.." when user clicks on button.
So change your xml's `android:onClick` to `android:onClick= "myButtonClicked"`

In the activity, implement this function

```
public void myButtonClicked(){

}
```

Finally, show the text "Congratulations!!! You are now initiated.." either via dialog (e.g. alertDialog) or in some textView

Answer (score 0):

You may have selected **"No Filters"** in android monitor which causes  **"Too much output to process error"**, Change it to **"Show only selected Application"** then all other Log line are filtered and will not show in Logcat.

[image: Here is snapshot of Android Monitor]